# "#N/A" not a valid date for type xsd:date

Tags: ruby, salesforce

I have a field in salesforce of type "date". It already has a date populated and now I want to set that null.

I tried passing "#N/A" to that field, which I think is the recommended way of doing it but it shows an error -

`'#N/A' is not a valid value for the type xsd:date`

I am using Ruby and basically doing this -

```
            DateFieldCustom__c:         assignment.completed_date || "#N/A",
```

Is there any other way of doing it? or it is not possible at all to do it?

Comment: Please edit your post and add in the code segment that shows us how you're passing the value to the field.  Also, add a tag for the language you're using.

Answer (score 0):

How are you sending that to SF. REST API (normal or bulk), SOAP API? Or do you "just" generate a CSV file and let SF Data Loader do the rest? `#N/A` is used in bulk api CSV from what I remember.

"xsd" suggests xml validation/schema definition so sounds like you're using SOAP API. Do you hand-crat the XML (yuck, escaping special characters etc manually) or did you consume a WSDL file?

Null should be fine but you need to pass it as separate node in the message. See [this example](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdjWwUAJ/allow-nulls-to-be-passed-as-a-valid-value-via-the-apis?sfdcIFrameOrigin=null) and search "fieldsToNull" on [this page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_concepts_core_data_objects.htm?q=fieldstonull)

Comment: Hello, Thanks for replying. Currently, I am using https://github.com/yatish27/salesforce_bulk_api library which ultimately uses https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_intro.htm which I think uses SOAP API. 

I am specifically using `upsert` API for this specific call. And we are consuming a WSDL file.

Comment: Looks like there's optional param you can play with, https://github.com/yatish27/salesforce_bulk_api/search?q=send_nulls. Try to read the library's documentation, worst case raise a new issue in that github repository asking for example?